# "(#100) Error finding the requested story" encountered when POSTing like on a post

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to get posts that a user is tagged in, and then issuing a like on the posts by `POST`ing to `[post_id]/likes`. However, even though the post obviously exists, because I was able to retrieve the `post_id`, when issuing the like, the following error is encountered:

```
(#100) Error finding the requested story
```

I find that this seems to affect only posts with `post_id` in the format of `[user_id]_[post_id]`.

Is this a known bug or is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you mistakes. I open user wall and see all posts is [user_id]_[post_id]. Most of this posts likes. But I also find several posts as you. 
For example: I and User are now friend...

Comment: If find another issue with this message: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/432337016792576?browse=search_4f8d828f3c07e5b68572935
But in own situation I think this not bug.
At web facebook present messages with label RECENT ACTIVITY. And this messages we can not like or comment.

Answer (score 1):

an old question but might help someone.
For me the issue was that if the post privacy is public then you can access in the way you doing and it works fine, but if the privacy has some custom setting then you will get the above mentioned error. 
The fix that worked for me was to get the permission "read_stream" from the user, if user gives you this permission than you can use the post in similar way as you are doing (i.e. [post_id]/likes )