# Like Facebook post of user, Who is not in my friend list or you can say liking a public post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have two Facebook test users A and B. Both users are using my Facebook app. As app in development mode, I give all the permissions to app for both the users and created the access token for both the users.

Now I can get feed of both the users A and B. So I found a feed of user B used post id is `238863083139817`. But when I tried to like the post of B from A using given bellow graph API.

```
POST/v2.6/1542696762701116_238863083139817/likes
```

I got the error message give bellow.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Error finding the requested story",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DH4NvDpj3aN"
  }
}
```

Here 1542696762701116 is my id.

Anybody know how can I like the post of user who is not in my friend list.

The same code will work if user A and B will be friends.

Comment: Please inline the error message instead of linking to an image.

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: may i ask what the use case for this is? i can´t think of any serious application for liking a facebook post with the api.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, it seems to be a problem with the permissions of the application. Maybe could you add some to check if the problem remains.

For instance, I saw that post: 
["(#100) Error finding the requested story" encountered when POSTing like on a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936057/100-error-finding-the-requested-story-encountered-when-posting-like-on-a-po)

It talks about the permission: read_stream that can help to solve your problem. 
Could you try and give your feedback?

Comment: I am using developer account and given all the permissions.